# It is bad practice to hard couple logging interface/implementation with business model classes?

Tags: java, design, logging, model

Should we avoid using logging in business model classes and try to move logging to service/controller classes?

In for example java context, logging in model classes will hard couple the code with dependencies on `slf4j` or `commons-logging` etc.

Answer (score 2):

One way of keeping your BL decoupled from the various logging libraries is to create a logging interface in one of your core libraries, which will be referenced by the BL. You can then have the concrete implementations in another library and inject them in the BL. This way your BL will remain oblivious to your logging library of choice.

As for logging in business model, it really depends on what you want to log. If it's just exceptions, you can let them bubble up and catch/log them in the upper layers. If you want to log more than exceptions, you'll have to add the logging code inside your BL classes, which isn't that bad. After all, logging is a cross-cutting concern and you're supposed to scatter it across all the layers of your application.

Long story short: no, it is not a bad practice.

Comment: As a side note: most logging is so trivial that it is easy to hit with search & replace across a whole project. The only complicated parts are configuration, but that would have to change anyway, if you switch the logging library.

Comment: @ChristianSauer even if it's trivial it doesn't mean that it should be approached with a simple search & replace, it looks a bit unprofessional.

Answer (score -2):

[Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) is a great way to separate the logging concern with from your other code. It's relatively easy to implement trace and exception logging in a single class.

Comment: how does this answer the question asked?

Comment: @gnat: Logging is the canonical example for AOP, though I'll grant you that this answer is relatively content-free.

Comment: @RobertHarvey and readers of the answers are supposed to find this out how? [Answer] guidance doesn't seem to favor content-free stuff: "Read the question carefully. What, _specifically_, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative..."

Comment: @gnat: Ehm, was your question rhetorical?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it was a straight question about this post

Comment: @gnat: Logging is a cross-cutting concern.  AOP is one way to approach cross-cutting concerns that doesn't require you to tightly bind every class in your program to an implementation to make it work.  devnull's answer sorta misses the point: it's the scattering that you want to try and *avoid*, not embrace.

Comment: @RobertHarvey if you want to use logging inside a method via AOP you're in for a bumpy ride. get it wrong and you have all the chances to bomb your application's performance. i was aware of this possibility at the time of the answer, i purposely omitted it for the reason stated above. i'm not saying AOP is not useful for other concerns, but for logging is a bit of an overkill IMHO.